# Conditional Formatting for one cell value in a list, another cell blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, cells

Looking for how to do Conditional Formatting for the following rule:

> If a number in a cell equals one of a list of particular numbers, then information MUST be entered into an additional cell. Both cells will turn RED until this is completed.

For example,

```
Material #   Batch    Fill   Line #
  83716      UP1278            1
  83715      UP1284            3
  83704      UP1287            4
  53716      UP1255            2
  26415      UP1291           12
  26415      UP1293           12
  56160      UP1257           10
```

When the cell in the `Material #` column contains the number 53716, 26415, or 56160, then this cell will turn RED as well as the cell on the same row that is in the `Fill` column.  BOTH cells will remain the color RED until the cell in the `Fill` column has data typed into it.

How should I set up conditional formatting for this when I want to do it for different numbers?

How do I make my list of this # or this # or this # or this # .......... and have the cells in both columns respond to the particular numbers by BOTH turning RED in color until the `Fill` column cell has data information typed into it?

Comment: How do you have both the `Material #` and the `Fill` cells behave this way? Simple: assign the same conditional format to both cells. What have you tried? Have you done any research? And how are the “particular numbers” determined? Are they the same for all rows? Are they constant for all time, or might they change? And, if they can change, where will the new values come from? (I.e., are they stored in the spreadsheet somewhere?)

Comment: I have used =$B$3:$B$14 for each of the numbers I listed in the Material column that I want to turn RED until data is entered into the Fill column ( then the RED would go away in BOTH columns ) .   This makes the cells I want in the Material column turn red but I cannot get the corresponding Fill cell to also turn RED.  And I cannot figure out how to make the RED stop for both cells once data is entered into the corresponding Fill column cells.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re saying about `=$B$3:$B$14`.  Look into the `AND()` and `OR()` functions, and try testing `$F1=""` (letting `F` represent the `Fill` column).

Comment: Keep getting error message.  Still trying to get both cells to turn red if the cell containing the first number equals a certain number and the second corresponding cell in the row is blank.  I will keep trying.

Comment: You ***keep getting*** [an] error message? What error message? This is the first time you’ve mentioned an error message. … … P.S. If J_V’s answer helps you, you should accept it (by clicking on the check mark).

Answer (score 0):

When introducing more complex conditions it's always a good idea to split them into smaller parts to begin with and combine them later on. Here you could first make sure that the cells turn red if a certain values are found in the first column.

`=OR($B1=value1;$B1=value2;$B1=value3;...)`

For the second condition you can use `""` to spot an empty cell as Scott stated.

`=$C1=""`

Now it's as simple as combining the two together with the `AND` function.

`=AND(OR($B1=value1;$B1=value2;$B1=value3;...);$C1="")`

[image: Formatting]

---

You can make the `OR` condition fancier by using a `Range` or a `Named Range`.

`=OR($B1=$A1$1:$A$100)`

[image: Range in the condition]

---

Note that you may have to swap all of the `;` to `,`.